# Select multiple of enum list

Tags: spring, jsp, binding, enums

How can I bind a list of enum in a multiple select ?

here is my class property (with the getter/setter):

```
private List<Color> colors;
```

And here is my jsp:

```
<form:select id="colors" path="colors" multiple="true">
  <form:option value="" label="..."/>
  <form:options items="${Color.values}" />
</form:select>
```

I couldnt get the enum values as array, because its empty.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It looks like you try to access your method "values" in a static way which looks strange to me as your attribute "colors" isn't static.

Comment: "Color.values" is from the Enum class Color. The class I show you is used as a commandObject for the form binding.

Comment: OK. It seems clearer now ^^

Comment: :) I found something to fix that, I give the enumeration values through modelAttribute from the controller instead.

Comment: If anyone have a better way to do that. Post it there :p

Comment: Why do you have a list of the same `Color` enums? Just pass `Arrays.asList(Color.values())` from the controller and then iterate with `items="{$theListAbove }"`..

Comment: I just wanted to store some colors from the Color enum. Actually that what I did, passing Color.values() from the controller to the view as I said. Did I answered your question ?

Comment: @fliim did your solution populate the `colors` field in modelAttribute form-backing object? It doesn't work for me. YOur solution shows enum values on the page but list of enums is not populated.

Comment: Instead of using these goofy tags you could do it in Java code printing out the HTML. Of course then you'd have to do it in a servlet to prevent anyone from having a heartattack.

Comment: @MyTitle What do you means by "YOur solution shows enum values on the page but list of enums is not populated" ? My list is correctly binded to my command object

Answer (score 6):

You seem to think that `${Color.values}` will call the static `Color.values()` method. That is incorrect.

Before Java EE 7 (Tomcat 8), there's no support for static methods in the JSP EL. `${Color.values}` will search for an attribute named `Color`, and, if found, call `getValues()` on this object. Since there is no such object in any scope, you won't have any option in your select box.

To do what you want, simply call `Color.values()` from your Spring controller and add it to the model, for example, under the `allColors` attribute name. Then use

```
<form:options items="${allColors}" />
```

in your JSP

If you're using Java EE 7, then you can import the Color class in your JSP, and use `${Color.values()}`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please, see my comment  under question. There is I desribed that my enum list in form-bacing object don't populated when user submits form. The problem with calling `Color.values()` - is the problem of OP, but I of course set all enum values from controller. And also all other attributtes of form-backing object populated nice, problem exist only with populating list of enums. But multiselect parameters are sent fine - I see all selected values of multiselect in FireBug

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You should create your own question, and show your form, your controller and your command bean. It all works fine on a simple example I just tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to get the enums as a List:

```
List<Color> colors = Arrays.asList(Color.values());
```

For a given enum:

```
    public enum Color {
        blue,
        red;
    }
```

Or have your getter return the array or List immediately:

```
    public Color[] getColors(){
        return Color.values();
    }
```

List

```
    public List<Color> getColorList(){
        return Arrays.asList(Color.values());
    }
```